# Проверка указателя на действительность

Tags: c

В C возможна сокращенная форма проверки указателя на действительность.

```
void *pointer = NULL;

if (pointer)
{
}
```

Как и почему это работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае в скобках после ключевого слова if заключено выражение, которое проверяется на неравенство нулю. Если значение выражения не равно нулю, то условный блок исполняется. В C инициализированный указатель не равен нулю. Следовательно, условный блок будет исполняться тогда и только тогда, когда указатель инициализирован.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая что главное требование к скрипту это межплатформенная переносимость и учитывая что вторая по популярности оси линупс не поддерживает локальную обработку исключений, то общего решения не существует. В сех заключить код нельзя, так на линупсах не будет работать, MmIsAddressValid() или любые другие функи, защищённые сех использовать нельзя, по тойже причине.

Кстати, если указатель не нулевой, это ничего не значит. Он может быть не нулевой и инвалидный.

Comment: Автор спрашивает не про причины неиспользования отлова исключений, а про одинаковость поведения `if(ptr)` и `if(ptr != NULL)`.

Comment: `MmIsAddressValid() или любые другие функи, защищённые сех` — а разве `MmIsAddressValid()` не обращается напрямую к таблицам виртуальных страниц?